# using routes and active-record for static variables inside the initializer

Tags: ruby-on-rails

We need to have some usernames to be excluded from using, but those might change with time.

having an idea like this and pretty much found out that wont work since in initializers theres no active-record nor routing

```
#initializer/usernames.rb
FORBIDDEN_USERNAMES = %W( admin superadmin owner ceo mail sex ..... )

Page.select(:url).map{|x| FORBIDDEN_USERNAMES << x.url}
Rails.application.routes.routes.select{|route|
  route = route.path.spec.to_s
  next if route == "/" || route.starts_with?("/:slug")
  FORBIDDEN_USERNAMES << route.split("/")[1].gsub("(.:format)", "") rescue next
}
FORBIDDEN_USERNAMES.uniq!
```

inside the `after_initializer` even the routing is still not present.

where can we put this stuff , or should we put that straight into the `user.rb`? so we need to put the logic into that method?

```
class User
  validates :username_is_allowed
  def username_is_allowed
    errors.add :username, "is not allowed" if FORBIDDEN_USERNAMES.include? username
  end
end
```

#### edit

Added this snipped to the routes.rb

```
Page.select(:url).each do |page|
  get page.url => "application#pages", url: page.url, format: false, as: page.url
 end
```

so then all my Pages are having their own route, and so for that i only need to loop thorugh the routes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could store this array in the `User` class. Then you can place the code inspecting the routes directly into the `routes.rb`. At the end of it you can be really sure they're loaded ;-) an you can add the found values to the `User::FORBIDDEN_USERNAMES` from there.

Comment: that was a great idea, to just put it at the end of the routes.rb! and where to go now with my Page.select ?

Comment: du hast fast die 1000 geknackt :-)

Comment: Where does the `Page` class come from? Is it a AR-Model?

Comment: i edited my post. its all good now. each url of our pages is having his own route